# Calendar with googleVis and googleCharts

Tags: r, googlevis

I am using a version 0.5.0-1 of googleVis and I want to make a calendar with gvisCalendar but from October 20, the calendar is empty.

I tried to change the locale but didn´t work.

```
install.packages(c("devtools","RJSONIO", "knitr", "shiny", "httpuv"))
library(devtools)
install_github("mages/googleVis")
library(googleVis)
cl1 <- gvisCalendar(Cairo, datevar="Date", 
                numvar="Temp", 
                options=list(width=1000))
plot(cl1)

sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RJDBC_0.2-3        rJava_0.9-6        DBI_0.2-7          shiny_0.8.0       
[5] googleCharts_0.1.0 ggplot2_0.9.3.1    zoo_1.7-11         plyr_1.8.1        
[9] data.table_1.8.10  googleVis_0.5.0-3 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bitops_1.0-6       caTools_1.16       colorspace_1.2-4   dichromat_2.0-0   
[5] digest_0.6.4       grid_3.0.2         gtable_0.1.2       httpuv_1.2.3      
[9] labeling_0.2       lattice_0.20-27    MASS_7.3-29        munsell_0.4.2     
[13] proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 Rcpp_0.11.0        reshape2_1.2.2    
[17] RJSONIO_1.0-3      scales_0.2.3       stringr_0.6.2      tools_3.0.2       
[21] xtable_1.7-1
```

I used a version 0.1.0 of googleCharts and happened the same.
Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if it's your web browser? Can you display the calendar plot on the following page?: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar